# Box where i can append written things

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, chat

I have to make a pseudo-chat, that will add  text fromt textarea after button is pressed to a box above the textarea. So far my code is looking like this

```
<form name="frm1" id="puts">
  <textarea name="txt1" COLS=15 ROWS=1></textarea>
  <a class="Sisesta Nupp" id="nupp5" href="#"
     onclick="alert(document.frm1.txt1.value) +(document.frm1.txt1.value='')"">
    <span>Sisesta </span>
  </a>
```

But how to get it written in a box above the textarea so that it won't erase previously written things from the above box? And how to draw a box, that will make a scroll, if the text doesn't fit anymore? When I write something then it should answer me with a random sentence from a list.

edit1: Since html is crap, and the two other solutions(which were good) don't work in my code, I would like to know, how can I just append the document.frm1.txt1.value in a box above my textarea?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to create with jQuery:

jQuery code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   $('#result').append('<br />'+$('#text').val());
   $('#text').val('').focus(); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='send' id='button'>
<div id='result'></div>
```

[Here you go! jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BUwN/) --edit:- [revised](http://jsfiddle.net/3BUwN/1/)

Comment: But where does it append? I need it to append to a box above the textarea

Comment: Okay, it works in jsFiddle, but it doesn't work in eclipse. After i push the button, it doesn't write anywhere and doesn't clear the textarea : /

Comment: @nils: Do you have jQuery included?

Comment: yep <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had a few minutes to kill (waiting on IM response), so I came up with this possibility, using the slightly amended html:

```
<div id="box">
    <ol id="chat"></ol>
</div>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <textarea id='text'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='send' id='button'>
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(
    function(){
        var text = $('#text').val();
        $('<li />')
            .text(text)
            .appendTo('#chat');
          $('#text').val('');
        return false;
    });

$('#text').keypress(
    function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == true){
           // might be a better way to do 'nothing'...
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#button').click();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BUwN/2/).

---

**Edited** to link to a revised demo (for that 'classic IM' look): [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BUwN/3/).

Comment: Your version looks interesting, but if I run it, It restarts the whole page from the beginning : /
And it still doesn't write anything anywhere as far as I can see. + the above box (place where the text is appended) is overrided by my background image.

Comment: nice one, even looks like a chat window +1

Comment: @rsplak, thank you kindly! :) @nils, any chance you can post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your own, showing what you're working with? So far both myself and rsplak have posted something that meets your stated requirements, but doesn't meet your needs. I think, to answer your question properly, we need to see what you're working with.

Comment: Hehe, okay, the code is looking terrible, but since it's my first time ever coding html etc. and I'm just tring to get things working
http://jsfiddle.net/wVQBL/3/ be gentle

Comment: @nils, thanks, but to load your `mängija.js` JavaScript, JS Fiddle will need an absolute path. Also, that seems to work as far as I can tell, what's the problem you're having with it?

Comment: ee, what do you mean by that? How do I set the absolute path?

Comment: @nils, `js/mängija.js` is a relative path, and absolute path is of the form `http://www.domain.tld/directoryName/fileName.filetype` (for example: [`http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/repo/css/reset.css`](http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/repo/css/reset.css)).

Comment: If i push send in jsFiddle, it still "refreshes" the result window and doesn't do anything. Just clears the textarea

Comment: @nils, what browser/platform? On Firefox 4, Chromium 10 and Opera 11 (Ubuntu 10.10) the 'chat' messages are appended to the chat window.

Comment: @nils: try this version of your demo, with some of the additional stuff removed: http://jsfiddle.net/wVQBL/4/

Comment: Everything except the contents of the `body` tag (including the opening, and closing `<body>` and `</body>` tags themselves).

Comment: Can you point out the problem? Or is my code just acting really weird?

Comment: @nils: not really, it's because everything in the `html` panel of JS Fiddle is inserted into the `body` tag of the iframe it creates to preview the code. The JavaScript pane gets thrown into the head, as do the libraries/css that can be selected/added on the left hand column. Similarly the CSS pane also gets put into the head. This is a simplistic overview, though. I assume the problem was invalid html, since the body can't contain a `head` or another `body` so far as I'm aware.

Comment: ohwell.. thank you very much anyway. So there isn't a way to get it working in my code?
now I'm convinced that every IDE should be made using user-centered design. It puts me off trying to learn some programming language.

Comment: @nils, if you're only just learning html, JavaScript and so on, I'd suggest learning with Notepad (or TextMate (Mac), Gedit or Kate (Linux)). That way you'll know why, or where, an IDE might be screwing up.

Comment: hey, but doesn't form refresh the page every time you use it?

Comment: @nils, it normally does, yeah; but the `return false;` in the button-click event handler prevents the button triggering the submit event.